# RESTEasy: In @PathParam("database") , how does program able to determine what "database" is? Could it have been any other place holder?

Tags: resteasy

I'm looking at this code, but please center on the word "database" below 
in public Object getDatabase(@PathParam("database") String db)":

```
package com.restfully.shop.services;

import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

/**
 * @author <a href="mailto:bill@burkecentral.com">Bill Burke</a>
 * @version $Revision: 1 $
 */
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerDatabaseResource
{

   protected CustomerResource europe = new CustomerResource();
   protected FirstLastCustomerResource northamerica = new FirstLastCustomerResource();

   @Path("{database}-db")
   public Object getDatabase(@PathParam("database") String db)
   {
      if (db.equals("europe"))
      {
         return europe;
      }
      else if (db.equals("northamerica"))
      {
         return northamerica;
      }
      else return null;
   }
}
```

In unit test, there's these two lines of code:

```
 Response response = 
 client.target("http://localhost:8080/services/customers/europe-db").request().post(Entity.xml(xml));
```

and also

```
 Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8080/services/customers/northamerica-db").request().post(Entity.xml(xml));
```

Question:  how is @PathParam("database") String db  able to pull the texts "europe" and "northamerica" ?

Is "database" a place holder and that the most important thing to note is that it's of type **String** since what follows is **"String db"** in "@PathParam("database") String db".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use URI Templates in a `@Path` annotation. Basically you define variable parts of a URI with an identifier in curly braces:

- `/customers/{id}/orders`
- `/~{username}`
- `/holidays/usa/{date}-{no}.jpg`

The part in the curly braces does not need to be a full path segment. `/{a}-{b}foo{d}_{e}/` is perfectly valid (if you find a meaningful example).

You can also you regular expressions in the URI Template. If you e.g. don't want to accept usernames with numbers you can use:

```
@Path("users/{username: [a-zA-Z]}")
```

`/users/pete1` will not be matched by the resource method and will result in a 404. See [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cp26/index.html) for more details.

If the identifier in the curly braces matches the value of the `@PathParam` annotation RESTeasy will fill the according parameter. You can use any primitive or type with a constructor that accepts a single String argument as parameter type (more possible types are [mentioned in the documentation](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html)). So if you have this domain class

```
class OrderId {

    public OrderId(String orderId) {
    ...
    }

 }
```

you can use it directly:

```
@Path("/orders/{id}")
public Order get(@PathParam("id") OrderId id)
```

Comment: Can I do this: @Path("/orders/{a}")  public Order get(@PathParam("a") OrderId id)    .. note that in question is "a" and "id".   Does "a" and "id" have to be the same variable name?  Thanks.  For whatever reason, SOF won't allow me insert newlines in my comment.  Then how am I suppose to ask a clarifying question?

Comment: The path part in curley braces must match the value of the `@PathParam`. The name of the variable does not matter.